# Run-Length Encoding - count is a variable behind

Tags: python

```
uncompressed = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
count = 1
uncompressed = list(uncompressed)
olength = len(uncompressed)
for x in range(olength):
    last = x-1
    current = x+1
    if uncompressed[x] == uncompressed[last]:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print uncompressed[x], count
        count = 1
```

If I were to enter laaaava, it prints 
l 1 
a 1 
v 4 
a 1

when it should print 
l 1 
a 4 
v 1 
a 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why your version isn't working, it might help to step through it and track the variables as you go through the loop:

```
uncompressed = ["l", "a", "a", "a", "a", "v", "a"]

**x = 0:**
last = -1
uncompressed[x] = "l"
uncompressed[last] = "a" # remember in python, negative index wrap around to the end
# these aren't the same so it will print "l 1"

**x = 1:**
last = 0
uncompressed[x] = "a"
uncompressed[last] = "l"
#these aren't equal so it will print "a 1"

**x = 2:**
last = 1
uncompressed[x] = "a"
uncompressed[last] = "a"
# these are equal so 
count = 2

**x = 3:**
last  = 2
uncompressed[x] = "a"
uncompressed[last] = "a"
# these are equal so 
count = 3

**x = 4:**
last = 3
uncompressed[x] = "a"
uncompressed[last] = "a"
# these are equal so
count = 4

**x = 5**
uncompressed[x] = "v"
uncompressed[last] = "a"
# these aren't equal so it will print "v 4"
```

... you get the idea.  As a hint to make it work, try looking ahead instead of behind

Hope this helps!

EDIT for comment:

I think you're almost there.  If you are looking ahead, you can't run through the whole string in the for loop because you will look past the end of the string during the final iteration, causing the `index out of range` error.

If you instead loop to the 2nd to last character, so `range(olength-1)`, then in the last iteration you check if the 2nd to last character is the same as the last character.  If they are the same, you increase the count, if they aren't the same, you print and reset the count to 1, just as you are doing in the code you originally posted.

Either way, when you exit the loop, all you have to do is print the last character and the count to finish it up after the loop exits.

Comment: I appreciate this a lot. I did go back and take the hint. My counts are finally correct up to the last number in a string - which does not print and is followed by a "list index out of range". I've tried to balance this out with some more conditionals but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No problem, i've added an edit at the end to try and help.  You're original code should be very close to working without many changes.

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't a learning exercise, the way you could do this is:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'laaaava'
for k, g in groupby(text):
    print k, len(list(g)),

# l 1 a 4 v 1 a 1
```